# How to calculate the correlation between two ratings

Tags: probability, correlation

Suppose *x* and *z* are two persons who rate a classical piece of music *y* on a five point scale.

> *x* rates *y* $3$ out of $5$
>
> *z* also rates *y* $3$ out of $5$

I need to know how much the ratings of *x* and *z* are similar.

I was thinking to create the difference between them. In other words:

> $3/5 - 3/5 = 0$

But I need a function that can change the zero to one, because obviously they are similar and have the same taste.

That same function should gives me zero if the difference is one. In other words, if:

> *x* likes *y* by $5$ out of $5$
>
> *z* likes *y* by $0$ out of $5$

The difference between them is one. Thus, that function should respect it.
I don't know what that function could be, **I don't even know if my proposal for making the difference is correct** could you help guys?

#### Update 1

I can't use $1-\text{difference}$ because if the case what *z* and *x* have expressed their opinions in not just $y$, but also $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$, I might end up with a negative value, while as you know the similarity must be between $0$ (not similar at all) and $1$ (identical taste).

Comment: maybe one minus the difference?

Comment: @citronrose well, I had already updated my answer before your commit :)

Comment: Are the values that you are comparing probabilities?

Comment: If you have many $y$s, you can use the correlation (divided by two plus 0.5 to have them between 0 and 1)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig no, they are ratings. Consider `x` and `z` are two persons, consider `y` as a classical song. Both of them expressed his/her opinion on that song by rating it. Then, I would like to know how much these two persons are close. In other words, how much their musical tastes are similar.

Comment: I would suggest making it clear in both your title and the question that you are trying to determine the correlation between two ratings.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig for some reasons, the system doesn't allow me to edit my question anymore. It states that too many spam from my network have been detected. Could you edit it yourself please ?

Comment: I made the edits.  Please check that I captured your intended meaning.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Perfect, many thanks for the edit and for telling me that what I'm looking for called `correlations`. I didn't know about it before, and I'm trying to read online.